# Transpose Rows to Column . 2 Varchar columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

[image]

Transpose rows to columns. I have 2 `Varchar` columns in SQL Server.

I cannot use pivot because I cannot run an aggregate on a `varchar` column. I have 2 columns `Name, Occupation`. Just need to transpose those.

Comment: "I cannot run an aggregate on a varchar field".  Maybe you can't, but the database can.  But if you want an answer to your question, you should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation  :

```
select max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name end) as Doctor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Actor' then name end) as Actor
from (select t.*,  row_number() over (partition by occupation order by name) as grp
      from table t
     )
group by grp;
```

Comment: Yes but this may not work in my requirements. I simply want to transpose two varchar fields. Please suggest.

Comment: @user3453057. . . Edit the question add expected result too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  It is not clear what you want, but perhaps:

```
select name,
       sum(case when occupation = 'Dog Groomer' then 1 else 0 end) as num_dog_groomers,
       sum(case when occupation = 'Airline Mechanic' then 1 else 0 end) as num_airline_mechanics
       . . .
from t
group by name;
```